# access denied error on executing stored procedure even though the permissions are there

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2

Our team upgraded from windows server 2003 to windows server 2012r2. The same user can execute a stored procedure on sql server 2008 on old server, but on the new server it throws access denied error. It does not make any sense.

```
     exec [activate_user] id
```

this is the exception I get

```
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): OA Error 0x80070005; source = CDO.Message.1; desc = Access is denied.
```

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: You should recreate the account for each database if you just restore databases into new instance of SQL server 2008

Comment: @Eric The sql server instance is brand new and it has been created the same way that we created it in windows server 2003.

Comment: Go to database's Properties and grant that user Execute permission

Comment: @Hakunamatata When I directly execute the stored procedure on sql server management studio.. it executes alternately. One time I get access denied and the second time it succeeds. I have no idea why it is doing that